# Error en acentos y tildes Codeigniter Angular

Tags: php, codeigniter

Al devolver un resultado en Codeigniter y Angular los acentos se convierten en

```
contrase\u00f1a
        ^^^^^^
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error?

Código PHP Codeigniter

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
$this->output->set_output(json_encode($response));
```

Código Angular

```
$scope.ErrorMessage = data.message;
```

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
function getMessage($key){
    $file = parse_ini_file('application/messages.properties');
    return $file[$key]; 
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías dar un poco más de detalle sobre cómo intentaste depurarlo? ¿De dónde estás obteniendo los datos, cómo están codificados, y cómo los estás imprimiendo?

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes configurado esto:

```
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
```

No creo que tengas problemas ya que a veces es el **lector o visor** que tienes y si en ese caso lo imprimes directo en la pantalla sin vista me refiero sin estructura HTML que tenga encabezado con **UTF-8** entonces es normal que te salga de esa manera, prueba obteniendo esa informacion y mostrarla en una vista con "UTF-8".